# Load balancing with Yii sessions

Tags: php, database, session, yii, load-balancing

I am trying to configure a load-balanced environment using Yii 1.1.14 applications, but I seem to be having the problem where Yii does not keep a user logged in when the load balancer uses another node. Most of the time, when logging in, it will ask the user to login twice because it only logs in on one node, and then loads the page on another. Otherwise, it will ask the user to login again half-way through browsing.

The application is using DB sessions and I can see that the expire time is being updated in the database. Even in the case when it asks them to login again straight after they have already logged in, the session expire time is updated in the database. Does Yii do anything server dependent with the sessions?

I've searched around for hours but unable to find much on this topic, and wondering if anyone else has come across such problem.

On the server-side, I am using Nginx with PHP-FPM and Amazon's ELB as the load balancer. The work around (as a last resort) is to use sticky sessions on the load balancer, but then this does not work the best if a node was to go offline and force the user to use an alternative node.

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything better.

Comment: had the same problem a while ago - concluded sticky sessions was the only way out.

Comment: @themosquitokiller actually, it is possible, we have it working on an app I'm working on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that the base path which was used to generate the application ID, prefixed to the authentication information in the session, did not match on each server. Amazon OpsWorks was deploying the code to the servers using the identical symlinked path, but the real path returned by PHP differed due to versioning and symlinking.

For example, the symlink path on both servers was '/app/current'. However, the actual path on one server was '/app/releases/2014010700' and the other was '/app/releases/2014010701', which was generating a different hash and therefore not working with the session.

Changing the base path to use the symlink path in my configuration file fixed the problem, whereas before it was using dirname() which was returning the real path of the symlinked contents. I also had to remove the realpath() function in setBasePath in the Yii framework.

The modifications I made to the Yii framework are quite specific for my issue, but for anyone else experiencing a similar issue with multiple nodes, I would double check to ensure each node contains the application in the exact same path.

Thank you to the following article: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/19574-multi-server-authentication-failure-with-db-sessions

Comment: Can you share your code in which you made change to remove  realpath() ?

Comment: @DharmeshGoswami Sorry, I no longer have that code available to me. I suspect this has also changed significantly in Yii 2.0. If you follow the URL I posted and the comments made, it may indicate what needs to be changed. From memory, it was a 1-2 line change.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd answered this before, but took a bit to find my answer:
[Yii session do not work in multi server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627999/yii-session-do-not-work-in-multi-server)

Short version: if you have Suhosin enabled, it's quite painful. Turn it off and things work much better. But yes, the answer is you **can** do ELB load balancing with Yii sessions without needing sticky sessions.

Comment: Unfortunately, Suhosin wasn't my issue. I did come across your article. It turned out to be that the paths on each server wasn't matching. I will post a full answer to this as soon as SO lets me. Thanks for your response!