# How to fix too many redirects yii 1.1.21 with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, yii, yii1.x

I have my yii 1.1.21 site in iis 8.5, but I need to migrate to nginx, I'm new in nginx so I tried use this guide:

(https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config)

All ok in the main page, but when I navigate in my site, almost all time have the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". I tried many solutions but nothing works.

I posted my default file below for more information:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/key.crt;        # path to your cacert.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/<sermername>.key;    # path to your privkey.pem
    server_name <server name>;
    server_tokens off;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-R$

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php

    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    proxy_read_timeout  1200s;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'";
    add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
#   add_header Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only

    access_log /var/log/nginx/default.access.log combined;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default.error.log warn;

    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
     location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }



    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
        set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

#        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
#        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

        #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;

    }

# prevent nginx from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days breaking my head, i found the solution, my site work with load balancing and yii sessions no work well with multi server by default.
My solution was enable CDbHttpSession to store the session in DB. 
More references:
[Load balancing with Yii sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962607/load-balancing-with-yii-sessions)
[Yii session do not work in multi server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627999/yii-session-do-not-work-in-multi-server)