# Scalability and Concurrency of YIi application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

How can I explain Scalability and Concurrency of YIi application to my client ?

These are the points They are asking

Scalability – the application should support web farms i.e. when multiple web servers are used to handle the load

Concurrency – The application should be able to handle the situations when multiple users try to update the same resource at the same time

Please help me with details .

Answer (score 3):

1) Yii supports multiple servers, but is tricky to implement.

Examples of problems you may face:

- [Yii session do not work in multi server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627999/yii-session-do-not-work-in-multi-server)
- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/3837-warning-if-deploying-across-multiple-load-balanced-webservers/

2) As for concurrency, you can implement a date/time updated field in all database tables, and check before saving the data to the server. If the data was updated by another user, get the updated record and merge the changes.

Comment: 'components'=>array(
   'securityManager'=>array(
      'validationKey'=>'xyz....',
   ),
)

Is this the best method? or db session ? or cache session ?